# In Perl, how do I import the sample CSV, do a basic text manipulation, then save it back to CSV?

Tags: perl, string, csv

Decided to try and learn Perl, and currently need to process a number of CSV files.

To get started doing more advance text manipulation I first need a base code that:

- Imports a local CSV
- Does a basic text manipulation
- Save the resulting changed values

The import/process/export should support 1000+ rows and 20+ columns. Going to supplies a sample CSV file, but feel free to supply one in your answer.

SAMPLE CSV FILE:

```
"EmployeeName","OfficeHistory","JobLevelHistory"
"John Smith",501,"Engineer"
"John Smith",601,"Senior Engineer"
"John Smith",701,"Manager"
"Alex Button",601,"Senior Assistant"
"Alex Button",454,"Manager"
```

If you have any questions, let me know — this will be a HUGE help in me getting started. My main focus is the text manipulation, but the manipulations are meaningless unless I've got a way to input data and export it back to a file. **Also, if you have any suggestion for quickly creating and debugging text manipulations that would be a huge help too.** (NOTE: Currently use an application to do this, but need more control, and decided to give Perl a try.)

Comment: What sort of text manipulations would you like to accomplish?

Comment: Common one is using Regex to extract a string. Though a view are very complex, meaning a number of steps. My notes on the text transformation aren't human readable, or I'd post them... :-) ...what would you like to know?

Comment: What is stopping you from using a database to store the csc and then manipulating it?

Load infile
Export outfile

Comment: @ThinkCode: The file goes to many tables, not just one -- though it's possible I'm misunderstanding you. I just figured it'd be additional overhead in the code to use the database directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) or [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV).

Anything else will drive you insane, sooner or later.  CSV is an unruly format in practice, though there are rules laid down ([RFC 4180](http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.html)) but they were defined somewhat *post hoc* so some systems, notably by Microsoft, handle them differently.  MS did indeed get there first, but there are differences between the CSV formats recognized by different MS products.

---

#### Rehash of Text::CSV manual page

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my @rows;

# Read the CSV file
{
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new()
        or die "Cannot use Text::CSV ($!)";
    my $file = "data.csv";
    open my $fh, '<', $file
        or die "Cannot open $file ($!)";

    while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh))
    {
        push @rows, $row;
    }
    $csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();

    close $fh
        or die "Failed to close $file ($!)";
}

# Munge the data
{
    foreach my $row (@rows)
    {
        foreach my $col (@{$row})
        {
            $col = uc($col);
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}

# Write the data
{
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new()
        or die "Cannot use Text::CSV ($!)";
    my $file = "output.csv";
    open my $fh, '>', $file
        or die "Cannot open $file ($!)";
    $csv->eol("\n");
    foreach my $row (@rows)
    {

        $csv->print($fh, \@{$row})
            or die "Failed to write $file ($!)";
    }
    close $fh
        or die "Failed to close $file ($!)";
}
```

#### Output based on your sample data

```
EMPLOYEENAME,OFFICEHISTORY,JOBLEVELHISTORY
"JOHN SMITH",501,ENGINEER
"JOHN SMITH",601,"SENIOR ENGINEER"
"JOHN SMITH",701,MANAGER
"ALEX BUTTON",601,"SENIOR ASSISTANT"
"ALEX BUTTON",454,MANAGER
```

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: +1 Thanks, really need a full sample script, I know zero Perl. Would this script do what I'm requesting, minus the simple text transformations, or is it missing something? http://szabgab.com/talks/fundamentals_of_perl/process-csv-file.html Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: "CSV is an unruly format in practice" I agree, these are only for me. After I'm done, I'm importing them into a database.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Wow, thank you... it works! Now the fun starts. Clearly you are the answer, thank you again.

Comment: Why read it all into memory, process it all, and then write it all out, when you can do it row-by-row?

Comment: @hobbs: Various reasons...  The primary one is that if the code was rewriting to the original file, if anything changes size, you need to read all before writing anything.  I could use two concurrently open file handles to separate files, one for reading, one for writing.  For the data in the sample (or the production sizes, by the sounds of it), reading all into memory is not going to be a big problem.  And because I'm demonstrating.

Comment: @blunders: the script you reference in your first comment is reading a CSV - not writing.  It is better than nothing, but not as good as you got from here :D

Comment: I see it as a demonstration of how to have lots of unnecessary code to confuse someone who admits to not knowing Perl at all, sorry. Only one loop is needed -- even if you're rewriting the file, because perl knows how to deal with that for you, but you're not. Just the way I see it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Yes, I agree, really like your code and agree memory is likely not an issue. Guessing that if I got over 10k in rows on 1GB of ram it might be, but who knows. Again, thank you - really nice code!

Comment: @hobbs: I understand your point, but it's easy to say the code is this or that, if you write a version, trust me... I will look at it, and I'll comment after I've used it.

Answer (score 2):

[Text::xSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3axSV) actually has, in my opinion, a much more pleasant interface than Text::CSV[_XS] and you might want to consider using it.

The basic invocation is as easy as

```
my $csv = Text::xSV->new(filename => "file.csv");
```

or even

```
my $csv = Text::xSV->new;
```

which will read from files named on the commandline (if there are any), or else read from standard-input, and write to standard-output.

From there, working with the data is as easy as

```
while (my @row = $csv->get_row) {
  # Do stuff with the fields in @row
}
```

or, if the first thing you do is

```
$csv->read_header;
```

then it will read the first row of the file as a list of field names, and then you can access your data like this:

```
while (my %row = $csv->fetchrow_hash) {
  print $row{EmployeeName};
}
```

which saves you from having to count the order of the columns and refer to them by number. Of course there are functions for output too and they're just as simple -- it's all in the docs. If you're both reading and writing, you create two different `Text::xSV` objects, one for input and one for output.

A fully-worked equivalent of the "uppercase everything" filter in the other answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::xSV;

my $in = Text::xSV->new("data.csv");
my $out = Text::xSV->new("output.csv");

while (my $row = $in->get_row) {
    for my $col (@row) {
        $col = uc $col;
    }
    $out->print_row(@row);
}
```

Since this is just a utility script, we're letting `Text::xSV` just throw an exception for us if there's any problem opening the file, which (unlike `open`) it will do.

Comment: +1 Thanks, very interesting. Code base is much, much smaller. In reviewing the CSPAN docs I was unable to find specs on passing files via the command line, where is this in the source? http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TILLY/Text-xSV-0.21/lib/Text/xSV.pm Or is this a default Perl command line arguement? Again, thank you!

Comment: It's a part of perl -- see `*ARGV` in http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlsyn . You don't need to worry about the mechanics of it right away though, just that Text::xSV will use it if you don't give it a filename or a filehandle to use, and you use it for reading.